# Calling groovy execute cross platform

Tags: groovy, gmaven-plugin

I am currently using gmaven plus to run a groovy command inside maven.

The command (for the sake of example) would be

```
git help
```

If I run it on linux I can do:

```
'git help'.execute().text.trim()
```

This however doesn't work on windows. Instead I need to do:

```
'cmd /C git help'.execute().text.trim()
```

Is there a cross platform way of doing this?

Comment: I can do `'git help'.execute().text.trim()` fine in a Groovy shell on Windows. Maybe try if it works outside Maven with a plain Groovy shell.

Comment: I did, I downloaded and run groovysh and got this issue. It works fine when I run it from git bash or from cygwin but not from plain command prompt (didn't try power shell). The problem is that most of the team works on linux or mac OS and a few run on vanila command prompt so I need it to work on both environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that it worked for others got me thinking and indeed the problem was with my own PATH configuration;

Apparently, if you define git in the path as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"
```

then when running from command it will find git. However, groovy will NOT find it.

On the other hand, if you define git in the path as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

i.e. without the "". Then everything works fine.

see also https://serverfault.com/questions/349179/path-variable-and-quotation-marks-windows